# Calling ActiveJob::TestHelper methods causes SystemStackError: stack level too deep

Tags: ruby-on-rails, integration-testing, rails-activejob

I'm using Rails 5.1.6 and Ruby 2.5.1 (though had the same error on previous builds).

Switching over a mailer from deliver_now to deliver_later. Works fine in my browser, however I'm stuck trying to get my integration tests working. Seemingly using *any* methods from ActiveJob::TestHelper triggers the following error:

> Error: SendJobToContactsTest#test_send_job_to_contacts:
>   SystemStackError: stack level too deep

Integration Test Code:

```
require 'test_helper'
include ActiveJob::TestHelper

class SendJobToContactsTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
...
end
```

This works fine:

```
assert_difference 'ContactJob.count', 1 do
    patch update_contacts_user_job_path(@user, @job), params: {job: {contact_ids: [ @contact2.id], message: {message_text: "This is a test"}}}
end
```

Using `performed_enqueued_jobs` triggers the SystemStackError:

```
assert_difference 'ContactJob.count', 1 do
  perform_enqueued_jobs do
     patch update_contacts_user_job_path(@user, @job), params: {job: {contact_ids: [ @contact2.id], message: {message_text: "This is a test"}}}
  end
end
```

Even just `assert_enqueued_jobs` without `performed_enqueued_jobs` triggers the SystemStackError:

```
assert_difference 'ContactJob.count', 1 do
  patch update_contacts_user_job_path(@user, @job), params: {job: {contact_ids: [ @contact2.id], message: {message_text: "This is a test"}}}
  assert_enqueued_jobs 1
end
```

And turns out even just calling an empty perform_enqueued_jobs block (with none of my code involved) triggers the stack level too deep issue:

```
perform_enqueued_jobs do
 # do something later
end
```

Answer (score 6):

Turns out the issue was where I had the include statement. Moving it within the class solved the issue:

```
require 'test_helper'


class SendJobToContactsTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  include ActiveJob::TestHelper
```

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem using the spec syntax:

before:

```rb
require 'test_helper'
include ActiveJob::TestHelper

describe MyJob do
...
```

fix:

```rb
require 'test_helper'

describe MyJob do
  include ActiveJob::TestHelper
```